# Rails views output is different than Puma web server logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby script called `abc.rb` in rails `config/initializers`

```
require 'http'

    class Abc

        def initialize(url)
            @url = url
            @doc = web_lookup(@url)
        end

        def web_lookup(url_to_open)
            begin
                return Nokogiri::HTML(HTTP.get(url_to_open).to_s)
            rescue
                "Please check your URL!"
            end
        end

        def frequency_count
            @word_array = @doc.css("p").text.split(" ")
            @occurance = Hash.new(0)
            @word_array.each {|x| @occurance[x.downcase] += 1 }
            @occurance.each {|x,y|
                if y > 5
                    puts "#{x} : #{y} times"
                end
            }
        end

    end
```

And I'm trying to access that script's class in a rails controller.

```
class UrlsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @url_to_check = Abc.new("http://ecodehut.com/linux")
  end

end
```

Everything is fine so far but when I call this variable in index.html.erb `<%= @url_to_check.frequency_count %>` output is this:

```
{"it’s"=>1, "like"=>1, "asking"=>1, "“should"=>1, "i"=>5, "go"=>3, "to"=>14, "school?”"=>1, "and"=>8, "“would"=>1, "get"=>1, "a"=>3, "job"=>1, "if"=>2, "school?”.list"=>1, "of"=>1, "advantages"=>1, "is"=>5, "never"=>1, "ending"=>1, "elaborating"=>1, "each"=>1,  "throw"=>1, "your"=>2, "mouse"=>1, "away"=>1, "this"=>3, "time."=>1, "keyboard"=>1, "all"=>1, "need"=>1, "mozart."=>1, "navigate..."=>1, "before"=>2, "we"=>1, "begin"=>1, "with"=>3, "configuration"=>1,  "here"=>1, "download"=>1, "install"=>2, "system."=>1, "after"=>1, "come"=>1, "back"=>1, "continue."=>1}
```

**But my expected output is this:**

```
to : 14 times
and : 8 times
you : 9 times
the : 6 times
```

**I'm not getting why rails printing everything inside the hash instead of the key values with values bigger than 5 like mentioned in the frequency_count method.**

**P.S: Abc.rb script results fine and dandy when ran in terminal using `ruby Abc.rb`**

Comment: It's because your abc.rb script returning ` @occurance` hash which has values as it's given. the desired output you are looking might printed on console log. (Because you are just printing it not storing in any variabe). Look your server logs to cinfirm

Comment: yes...as I mentioned I can see the right output in console logs

Comment: I tried saving it into a variable too but then there is no output

Comment: Plese try my answer, it works @Meimo

Comment: it worked at some extent but formatted output a hash...when I try to use `puts` or `if and else` it just prints nothing except empty `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plese change this and try again

```
def frequency_count
    @word_array = @doc.css("p").text.split(" ")
    @occurance = Hash.new(0)
    @word_array.each {|x| @occurance[x.downcase] += 1 }
    @occurance.select {|x, y| y> 5}
end
```

The reason is the last line of your method is

```
@occurance.each {|x,y|
                if y > 5
                    puts "#{x} : #{y} times"
                end
            }
```

Just iterate all key and values inside `@occurance` variable but not sort based on the count. So you are getting all key values in the views instead which has count more than 5.

When you do `@occurance.select {|x, y| y> 5}`, which filter your hash and gives you the desired values which count is more than 5. Now you can just loop it and print inside views.

Hope you understand.

**Update**

In your `index.html.erb` put this code, where you would like to print hash details

```
<% @occurance.each do |key, value| %>
    <span><%= "#{key}: #{value}" %></span><br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: ok..it does only print y>5 but it still covered in hash parentheses `{"to"=>14, "and"=>8, "you"=>9, "the"=>6} ` . and it's still not my expected format. What I'm tryna achieve is this: `to : 14 times
and : 8 times
you : 9 times
the : 6 times` as you could see at the end of my question

Comment: Can't you do a `.each` loop and print the details from hash to what ever format you want?? @Meimo

Comment: How surprised would you be if I show you the results. So as you said I used `.select` and saved it in a variable like this  `@shortlisted = @occurance.select {|x,y| y > 5}` and then I did this `@shortlisted.each {|x,y| puts "#{x} : #{y} times"}` and result is `{"to"=>14, "and"=>8, "you"=>9, "the"=>6} `. It's as same as previous output of `.select`. However, I can see expected results in web server console but can't achieve the same in views. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: I have 11 methods inside this class and everything else is golden except this method. It is the only method with iteration. Rest of the methods output is fairly desired but I'm having trouble with this only.

Comment: Please try the updated answer. Am not familiar with Haml synatax much. @Meimo

Comment: @Meimo Try the above code it works for sure. Please read more about looping in rails views.

Comment: That precisely didn't work but after a little amends it worked :D `- @url_to_check.instance_variable_get(:@shortlisted).each do |key, value|
            %span= "#{key}: #{value}"` Thanks man...Oh and in my controller I had to call `@url_to_check.frequency_count too...Thanks again